# gyp error while installing angular gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, git, gulp

trying to create a gulp task runner with angular . followed the textbook instruction (https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular ). but when i execute yo gulp-angular . i am getting all these gyp error saying python and all. my computer currently dont have python . below are the screenshot of errors . i tried variable path change in environment variable , tried it on git shell, node, power-shell . git is installed on my pc as well

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled node, git, did a a good old fashioned restart. working like a charm now